# Webservice call returns "401 Authorization Required"

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I'm calling a third party webservice which uses credentials to validate the request. below is the code.

```
SmsWSIService smsService = new SmsWSIService();
smsService.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(smsUserName, smsPassword);
smsService.PreAuthenticate = true;                


SendSMS.SendSMS objSendSmsReq = new SendSMS.SendSMS();
objSendSmsReq.From = smsFrmMobNo;
objSendSmsReq.Message = smsMsg
objSendSmsResp = smsService.SendSMS(objSendSmsReq);
```

but its giving me the error "401 Authorization Required". I'm sure that the credentials which i'm passing are correct. The webservice doesn't give any error when I check it with the SOAP UI 3.5.

Please help where I'm going wrong.

Comment: check for service.proxy.credentials.

Comment: @Jodha I added proxy credentials and now its giving NullReferenceException

Comment: can you see the inner exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed Windows Authentication on IIS?

Comment: The application which I'm testing is a standalone application.